# Define map bounds and center on player node?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm working on a sidescroller with Spritekit and Swift. I don't understand how to define a playable area bigger than the screen and center the camera on the player. How can this be done?

This is my current code, I tried to create a "world node" which I could move around to simulate the camera, however it's somehow disassociated from it's shape and I haven't been able to get the player inside it.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.size = CGSizeMake(view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height)

    // Add world
    let r : CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)
    world = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: r.size)
    world.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: r)
    world.strokeColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    world.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    self.addChild(world)

    // Add player
    player = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    player.fillColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    player.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    world.addChild(player)

    // Accelerometer updates
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
}
```

Comment: You are going to need to provide more information than what we see above. Do you have a scrolling background ? Nothing I see above seems to indicate that.

Comment: sprite kit programming guide has an example for scrolling and centering on a node (note that there is no camera object)

Comment: I don't have an scrolling background but I don't want to add one at this moment. I just want to create a simple rectangular space I can move the player. I already created a black rectangular space bigger than the screen, but as I don't know how to center on the player he can get out of the camera range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example in Apple's documentation is in the [Advanced Scene Processing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH4-SW32) section.  Apple suggests making a "World" *SKNode* as a child of the Scene, and a "Camera" *SKNode* as a child of the world.

They suggest constantly moving the world so that it centers on the Camera during the *didSimulatePhysics* step.  This method allows you to perform actions or simulate physics on the Camera itself, if you so choose.  If you center the camera prior to this step, you won't be able to use physics to affect the Camera Node.

If you specifically only want left and right scrolling, simply restrict the movement to the X-axis.

Edit:
The current problem is because of your creation of the world and the physicsBody from a Rect that has its position predetermined.  This is causing trouble with your anchorPoint setting (the world & physicsBody are being created with their lower left corners starting at the Scene's anchor point).

This can be fixed by creating the World and Player without using a Rect with position set.  SKShapeNode's `shapeNodeWithRectOfSize` works, as does SKSpriteNode's `spriteNodeWithColor:size:`   PhysicsBody is a bit trickier, and should likely use `bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath: world.path`

EDIT: For future persons interested in creating a side-scroller with a camera always focused on the player, this is probably the simplest way to get one to work:

```
var player = SKShapeNode()
var world = SKShapeNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.size = CGSizeMake(view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height)

    // Add world
    world = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSizeMake(300, 300))
    world.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromPath: world.path)
    world.fillColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    self.addChild(world)

    // Add player
    player = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    player.fillColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    world.addChild(player)
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    world.position.x = -player.position.x
    world.position.y = -player.position.y
}
```

Comment: Hi AttackFarm, please see the edit, I could mostly figure it out. However my player for some reason the "world" node is in a different position than it's drawing and my player appears outside it instead of inside.

Comment: Hey, I could get it done with your suggestions. I just modified the world to use edgeLoopFromPath. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @AttackFarm, could you take a look at this question? I think it's a similar issue. I'm using `enumerateBodyiesInRect()` and when I show the rect on the screen, the rect appears on one area and the area evaluated for nodes is completely different. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851309/get-a-list-of-nodes-in-an-specific-area

Comment: I actually already was.  I tested out some code last night, but had to stop before I came to any real conclusions, other than that enumerateBodiesInRect() is really, really, really buggy.  It gave me  false positives in almost every situation, and gave me false negatives in other situations.  I'm still fairly stuck on it, but I'll take a look at it again in a bit

Comment: Thanks, could it be because it's a beta? I'll probably use bodyAlongRayStart, I hope it's not as bad

Answer (score 0):

I followed Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on a side scrolling game Super Koalio (or something like that). That game is a side scroller where the game map is larger sideways than the screen.  The following code is for my game which is a vertical scrolling game.

In the update method I call a method called setViewPointCenter.

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
  {
    // Other things are called too
    [self setViewPointCenter:self.player.position];
  }
```

Then in that method you just update the view

```
- (void)setViewPointCenter:(CGPoint)position
{
  NSInteger x = MAX(position.x, self.size.width / 2);
  NSInteger y = MAX(position.y, self.size.height /2);
  x = MIN(x, (self.map.mapSize.width * self.map.tileSize.width) - self.size.width / 2);
  y = MIN(y, (self.map.mapSize.height * self.map.tileSize.height) - self.size.height / 2);
  CGPoint actualPostion = CGPointMake(x, y);
  CGPoint centerOfView = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
  CGPoint viewPoint = CGPointSubtract(centerOfView, actualPostion);
  self.map.position = viewPoint;
}
```

Now my character is always in the center of the screen.  I did change some items from horizontal to vertical, but at least you get an idea.  Also, I used a tile map that is why you see mapSize and tileSize.  You might want to take a look at Ray's tutorial.  And of course you will need to convert into the methods into Swift!!

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work. My character is a physicsBody and is subject to gravity and such. Would I be able to keep it in the center on the screen while maintaining it's properties?

Comment: I made my own gravity in my player class, but other than that it has many other physicsBody properties, friction, restitution, no rotation and such.  Just not gravity from the Sprite Kit engine.

Comment: Hi Douglas, I read the Super Koalio post and downloaded the source code, I tried to implement something similar with a "map" / "world" node but can't get it to work. Please see the edit.