# How can i make a node collide with the sides of moving scene?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody

Hi i wish to know how can my nodes can collide with a moving scene. I have a main node that cans move along the x axis and cans collide with other nodes. I want to make the non main nodes collide with the sides of the moving scene. How can i make that ? ( the camera only follow the main node).

I have an obstacle class.

in my MLObstacle.m

```
-(id)init
{
if(self = [super init])
{
int aux = arc4random()%3;
switch (aux) {
    case 0:
        self = [MLObstaculo spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake((aux+1)*10,(aux+1)*13 )];
        break;
    case 1:
        self = [MLObstaculo spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blueColor] size:CGSizeMake((aux+1)*10,(aux+1)*15 )];
        break;
    case 2:
        self = [MLObstaculo spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake((aux+1)*10,(aux+1)*14 )];
        break;
}
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.size];
self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;

self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = obstacleCategory;
self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = visibleSidesCategory;
self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = visibleSidesCategory;   
[self setDx:0.0];
[self setDy:2.4];
}
return self;
}
```

So i add Obstacles to my WorldClass

In my WorlGen.m

```
-(void)GenerateWorld
{
SKSpriteNode *Ground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(self.scene.frame.size.width,100)];
Ground.position = CGPointMake(0, -self.scene.frame.size.height/2 + Ground.size.height/2);
Ground.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:Ground.size];
Ground.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;


[self addChild:Ground];
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{

    MLObstaculo * auxobs= [[MLObstaculo alloc]initObstaculo];
    auxobs.position = CGPointMake((i+1)*50, Ground.position.y + Ground.size.height/2 +auxobs.size.height/2 );
    [self.Obstaculos addObject:auxobs];
    [self addChild:auxobs];
    auxobs = NULL;

}
}
```

and then i add the world to my scene

Scene.m

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
     if(self = [super initWithSize:size]
     {
        WorldGen * world = [[WorldGen alloc] init];
        self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
        self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = VisibleSidesCategory
        self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ObstacleCategory;
        self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);
        [self addChild:world];
        [world GenerateWorld];
     }
}
```

Update...

```
-(void)didSimulatePhysics
{
    [self centerOnNode:hero];
}

-(void)centerOnNode:(SKNode *)node
{
    CGPoint pointinScene = [self convertPoint:node.position fromNode:node.parent];
    world.position = CGPointMake(world.position.x -pointinScene.x , world.position.y);

}
```

I initalized all the category variables with this format  ( `static const uint32_t ObstacleCategory = 0x1 <<1;` )

Answer (score 1):

First edit by defining your collisionBitMask

```
-(id)init
{
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.size];
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ObstacleCategory;
    self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = VisibleSidesCategory;
    self.physicsBods.collisionBitMask = VisibleSidesCategory;
}
```

Second make this steps in Xcode -> **File** -> **New** -> **File** -> **C and C++** -> **Header File**

Give a name of Physics.h and add those lines in it:

```
typedef enum : uint8_t {
    ObstacleCategory            = 1,
    VisibleSidesCategory        = 2,

} ColliderType;
```

and then import Physics.h **into all your classes** (You don't need to alloc or init for Physics.h, just use ObstacleCategory and VisibleSidesCategory)

Comment: did u add physics also to non main nodes?

Comment: I tried your code. I know that should work because it's also in the Ios developer documentation, but it doesn't work. 
I already wrote code in the didBeginContact method. But still nothing.

Comment: did u wrote this code inside to -(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {   and also does all your nodes have physics? yes this code should work, I use in my apps too

Comment: yes, all my nodes have physics. My nodes actually can collide with everything but with the sides of the moving scene.

Comment: does all your nodes have unique categoryBitMasks and also can u check collisionBitMasks of all your nodes too, this can be the source of problem

Comment: Ok, here is the thing. All my nodes have unique categoryBitMasks. Something important is that i don't add my SpriteNodes directly to the scene. I have a "world" class node that is a simple node. So i add everything first to the world and then i add the world to the scene.

Comment: This doesn't make any problem, cause you add world node to scene as a child. Can you please share the code where you create your nodes and set your self(scene), so I can help you better

Comment: @XtDiego I edited my post, I think now you gonna solve your problem now

Answer (score 0):

From this and another question's problem, I have finally determined there is an error in the API.  Specifically, a node's anchorPoint is considered (0,0) during initialization if using a `WithRect:` or `FromRect:` based initializer(but not a `RectOfSize:` or `center:` based one), so you get unexpected behavior.

Thus, even when the anchorPoint of the Scene and other objects are set to (0.5,0.5),  a node places its lower left corner relative to the parent node's midpoint, rather than placing the child's midpoint relative to the parent node's midpoint.

Specifically, this can be solved in any one of these three ways:

1. Use an anchorPoint of (0,0).
2. Create your nodes without using Rect based initializers.  You can use `shapeNodeWithRectOfSize:` instead of `shapeNodeWithRect:` and `bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath:` instead of `bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:`
3. Set the Rect's initial position as lower and to the left, like so:

`node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:CGRectMake(-node.size.width/2, -node.size.height/2, node.size.width, node.size.height)];`

Comment: Ok i set the Obstacles as handling collisions. But the problem persists.

Comment: What exactly is happening?  From your code and everything you describe, if the bit masks are set and applied correctly, the obstacle shouldn't be ignoring the edge, so it would help to know exactly what you see when you run your code.

Comment: Also, is there a reason your Obstacle's unit doesn't call its super's init?

Comment: @XtDiego I edited my answer to provide a solution to the problem with what you've said.  I believe the second point, the lack of an anchorPoint, may be the problem you're having.

Comment: My anchor point is set in my project code as well as my super init callings of my classes. The problem persists. What really happens is that when my obstacles collides with my main node and they fly away , when they contact with my scene edges they should collide, but the nodes just pass over.

Comment: From the code you've posted, it's difficult, if not impossible, to determine the problem.  You don't have an anchorPoint set in that code, so I assumed that was the problem.  I think you'd have to either give more code or more information to figure out why this is happening.  Try polling the positions of the physics bodies to see if they are even where they should be.

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry , I'm new at this things. I'll post more info

Comment: Don't worry about it.  One thing you might try doing is calling bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath instead of bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect.  There seems to be some problem with bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect: self.frame that prevents expected behavior    I edited the first item in my answer's list to reflect this suggestion

Comment: How do i actually use property path for my scene  ? I mean. I can't set self.path for the bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath: method. Sorry i'm new

Comment: It's okay.  As I said in my answer, you create a node of the size you want (don't use any initializer that takes a rect, use one that takes a RectOfSize), then create the physicsBody with EdgeLoopFromPath:  node.path

Comment: Sorry, I meant specifically create a SKShapeNode of the size you want, then use that node's path property.

Comment: @XtDiego I edited my answer one last time with what I am pretty sure is your problem.

Comment: I added this line of code `self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:CGRectMake(-self.frame.size.width/2,-self.frame.size.  height/2,self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.height)];` but the problem persists

Comment: You're using self.frame.  Use instead the dimensions of a node of the size you desire, not the frame.  In my test code, the physicsBody was attached to a "world" node that was the main child to the scene.

Comment: I tested that same line, and it works in my code.  Try the second solution.  Utilize a ShapeNode and a PhysicsBody made with bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath: node.path

Comment: Ok i used the world's physics body and it partially works. However, when my camera moves following my main node i can notice that the "rect" physicsbody of the world that makes collision with the non-main nodes is static, it doesn't move following the camera.

Comment: I didn't realize you were using a moving camera.  That makes your problem very similar to this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748247/define-map-bounds-and-center-on-player-node/24843989#24843989

Look up my answer on that question.  Utilize a "world" node and a "camera" node, and move the world node so that the camera is placed back in the center every frame during the didSimulatePhysics() step/method.

Comment: what is exactly the camera node for ? i can just call centeronNode() method on my hero node and the " camera " will automatically follow my hero. So why should i create a camera node ? .

Comment: You don't need to.  Moving the world to center the player is fine for the most part.  However, theoretically you might want the camera to not be perfectly aligned with the player character, or you might want to show some effect or pan the camera or any number of options that would warrant a distinct camera node.  But it's certainly a situational need that might not apply to you

Comment: Ok then. So finally, if have a world and camera node centering on my main node, then how do i make all non main nodes collide with the edges of the camera ?

Comment: Same way as above.  Ensure there's a boundary.  If it's on your world object, ensure you use `edgeLoopFromPath`, not `edgeLoopFromRect`.  I haven't tested it out, but there's a change you need to make your edgeLoop a physicsBody of the Scene and not the World, depending on how the camera centering affects the collisions.  I'm sure one of them will be satisfactory

Comment: i realized that edges are static and it only applies for non scrolling content. However, i do have scrolling content. So edges are not useful for my case. I guess.

Comment: Which is why it may be useful for you to use an edge loop on the scene, not the world.  That way, as the world gets scrolled, the edge loop stays right where it is.  Because it's a body of the parent of the world, it won't get adjusted.

Comment: According to  [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW1) Edge loop physicsbody on the scene are used only for non scrolling contents. I'm confused.  ".. is used frequently in games that do not need to scroll the content." refering to a scene with EdgeLoop physicsbody

Comment: I myself am confused why you want both scrolling and a screen boundary, but there shouldn't be anything strictly disallowed as long as you ensure the `edgeLoop` follows the scrolling.  You could place it as the body of the `Scene` itself, or maybe the body of the camera.  Note that being "static" just means that the `physicsBody` isn't moved by the *simulation*.  It can still be moved manually by you, or by `SKAction`s acting on the body's node.  You just can't have some node, say, ram into an `EdgeLoop` and knock it around.  It's static until you decide to move it.