# using SKScene or SKShapeNode for a game world

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm following [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748247/define-map-bounds-and-center-on-player-node) advice on how to create my game world for a scroller game with camera centered on the player. However, the advice says to use an SKShapeNode; I don't know how I feel about that.

Are there any advantages/disadvantages to using either a shape node or an skscene (or another type of object/node)? Is there a node that is considered best practice to use as a world?

Also, is it possible to create an skscene inside an skscene, or is that bad practice/discouraged?

Thank you!

Comment: it depends on how you define "world" - generally speaking the scene is the world, and it can contain both visual and non visual nodes. Each node has a clear purpose. You wouldn't use a label where you need a shape, nor would you use a shape where you don't need any visuals and a sknode would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put a scene inside a scene per-say but you could stagger view controllers and place a view controller on top of another and then put the scene on top of that inset view controller.

The way I implement my scroller games is to put the player in the center and then move the background around. (Checking for bounds of course.)

As far as your advantages/disadvantages I'm not sure what you mean by the SKNodes; that's how you should do it if you're working just in SpriteKit. But don't add another SKScene unless you have something that you can't implement in just one SKScene.

Comment: what are your thoughts on using an skshapenode vs an sknode for the world node?

Comment: @AbdulAhmad I don't know why they suggest using an SKShapeNode. I would just use an SKNode unless there is a compelling reason to use a SKNode subclass's properties. (Example: texture on SKSpriteNode)